# how to tell pip to uninstall python modules from previous python version?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, python3, pip

I upgraded from Ubuntu `20.10` to `21.04` & the `python version` changed from `3.8` to `3.9`. In `20.10` I installed many python modules using `pip` & they are at `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/` & they are occupying a lot of space so I tried `sudo pip uninstall name` but `pip` says no such module installed even if it is there at `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/` I think it searches it only in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/` which were installed in `21.04` so how do I tell `pip` to `remove python modules` from `python version 3.8`?

Comment: `pip` is only aware of the current python version.  You will have to go erase a few things yourself after an upgrade like this one - cleaning out the old Python stuff.

Comment: so how can I do it manually in the safest way? rm or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Python has own `pip` and check if you can do

```
pip3.8 uninstall ...
```

You can also try

```
python3.8 -m pip uninstall ...
```

If you don't have `pip3.8` and there is no `python3.8` then system doesn't use this version and you can simply delete folder

```
sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/python3.8
```

---

Using `pip -V` you can see for what version it works. The same `python -V` show python version.

If you have many versions installed (ie. `2.7`, `3.8`, `3.9`) then you should have programs `python2`,`python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.8`, `python3.9` and `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.8`, `pip3.9`

Comment: I have python 2.7   3.8   3.9 but pip  version only one 20.3.4

Comment: if you can run `python3.8` then you can use `python3.8 -m pip ...`

Comment: number `20.3.4` is not important. When you run `pip -V` then it should show `pip 20.3.4 ..... (python 3.8)` or `pip 20.3.4 ..... (python 3.9)` and important is if it shows `3.8` or `3.9`

Comment: pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9) this is what I get after pip -V

Comment: so it is `pip` only for `python 3.9` and you should use `python3.8 -m pip uninstall ...` to unistall in `python 3.8`

Comment: it says python 3.8 command not found I think pip is ignoring the previous py versions

Comment: did you use `python3.8` without space ? Every python has own module `pip` and one `pip` doesn't ignore other `Python` because it works ONLY with own `Python` - if `pip -V` shows `python 3.9` then it is installed ONLY for `python 3.9`  and it will never works with `python 3.8`. And this is why system should have `pip3.8` to work ONLY with `python 3.8` and `pip3.9` to work ONLY with `python 3.9`. And system may have copy of `pip3.9` (or link) with name `pip` to make life simpler

Comment: if you can't run `python3.8` then you don't have it and you can delete folder manually.

Comment: sorry I don't have enough reputations for upvoting. thank u